# How do I stop scroll bar from appearing in dataTable?

Tags: primefaces

I'm working on a web app using primefaces. I'm using a dataTable and everytime I move my mouse in to the table, a scroll bar appears on the bottom, and occasionally on the right. I don't want or need this scroll bar.
[image: Mouse inside the table and useless scrollbar appears on the bottom]

```html
<p:dataTable var="o" id="territoryTable" widgetVar="territoryDataTable" value="#{searchTerritory.lazyModel}" lazy="true" dynamic="true" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="#{configParams['dataTable.row.default']}" styleClass="dataTableMargin"
  rowKey="#{o.id}" selectionMode="single" rowsPerPageTemplate="#{configParams['dataTable.row.values']}">

  <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{searchTerritory.onRowSelect}" />
  <p:ajax event="filter" ignoreAutoUpdate="true" />

  <p:column headerText="#{messages['territory.id']}">
    <h:outputText value="#{o.custom_id}" />
  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="#{messages['territory.name']}">
    <h:outputText value="#{o.name}" />
  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="#{messages['territory.description']}">
    <h:outputText value="#{o.description}" />
  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="#{messages['status.active']}">
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox disabled="true" value="#{o.activeFlag}" />
  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="#{messages['territory.coordinator.TerritoryManager']}">
    <h:outputText value="#{o.territoryManager.name}" />
  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="#{messages['territory.coordinator.status']}">
    <h:outputText value="#{o.territoryManager.activeFlag eq true ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}" />
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Anyone got ideas on how to remove it?

Comment: This is not the default behaviour... Most likely your custom css messes things up. Or Maybe you have zoomed in your browser?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a pure css solution where you just hide the scrollbar. Content that overflows will be hidden.

You need to insert in your css the following:

```
.dataTableMargin .ui-datatable-tablewrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

where `dataTableMargin` is you given styleClass and `ui-datatable-tablewrapper`is a wrapper around the datatable content.

PS: make sure, that your content is always inside the given view. Otherwise too big contents will be just cut off.

Comment: I just realized it happens chrome, when I use IE, I get no issue.

Comment: @LiamPaquette: PF version? And did you read my comment about zooming?